How to duck ROS and Gazebo questions while reviewing?
For personal reasons, I have an aversion to questions about ROS, Gazebo, etc. In fact, my browser's "home" page has a search-like link that filters them out with something like "-[ros*] -[gazebo*]". Every so often, though, I respond to the call of civic duty, and go to review the queue of posts from new users. But then I have to click "Skip" many, many times to move past the stuff I don't know about, don't care about, and don't want to consider.
Wouldn't it be great if there was a way to filter the topics to be reviewed, based on what I'm competent at and motivated to respond to?

You can register tags to ignore when logged in.

They support wild cards too.

Simply specify one or more asterisks to match any number of characters, either in the middle, the beginning, or the end of a tag. So all these should work as you might expect:

